# SDS Laemmli Gel that did not solidify

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology

In my lab class this week my partner and I were making a SDS-PAGE Laemmli Gel. We made the resolving gel solution which was made of 30% Acrylamide, DI water, 1.5 M Tris-HCL pH8.8, and 20% SDS. We mixed the measured amounts into a conical vial. We then added 10% APS and TEMED and mixed carefully. We then immediately pipetted the solution into the casting stand so the gel could solidify. We then pipetted DI water onto the top of the gel so it would not dehydrate. We left some solution in the conical vial so we knew when the solution would be solidified completely. After waiting 45 minutes the gel in the conical vial was solidified but the gel in the casting stand was still liquid. How come the gel did not solidify in the casting stand but solidified in the conical vial?

Comment: How long is your polymerization time? How old are APS and TEMED? Why do you use water on top and not an alcohol?

Comment: the polymerization time was said to be ~30-45 minutes. The TEMED was provided to the class so I'm not sure how old it was but the APS was made during the lab. Also the teacher suggested to use DI water so the gel would not dehydrate. Would it be the water that could have caused it to not solidify because that's the only thing that was not added to the conical vial which did solidify

Comment: You put a liquid on top of the gel because you want to avoid contact with the air. Air catches the free radicals needed for the reaction. Water can mix with your solution and dilute it (depending on the amount of water used and how cautious you pipetted it), thats why I usually use a few hundred microliters of isopropanol.

Comment: The polymerisation time appears to be rather long. From personal experience, it rarely takes more than 15 minutes for both the gel in the falcon tube and casting stand to solidify. How much APS and TEMED did you add?

Comment: The water shouldn't be an issue if it's layered carefully.

Comment: I would guess that the casting glass may have ethanol from cleaning process, or the water you added diluted mix.
Sorry for not entering this as a comment, for I dont have the necessary rep.

Comment: We added 150 ul of 10% APS and 15 ul of TEMED. The water was also added a couple drops at a time alternating between each end of the casting stand.

Comment: I don't understand, how do you know that the gel mix did not polymerize in between the glass plates? For example, did you attempt to remove the layer of water so that you could pour the stacking gel and discovered that the entire solution remained liquid? The liquid that you layer on top of the freshly poured gel serves two functions. As mentioned by others it excludes air (oxygen) that would inhibit polymerization. It also helps to form a smooth flat surface to pour the stack. 0.1% SDS works nicely too. Best bet: the plates were not clean enough and inhibited polymerization.

Comment: This is very strange. I used the variables given [here](http://www.assay-protocol.com/molecular-biology/electrophoresis/denaturing-page) and yet it solidified much faster. Additionally, I remember the one time I added 50µl of TEMED instead by accident and the gel solidified within 30s after vortexing. I agree with @mdperry's conclusion that the glass plates could have been dirty, or that the TEMED was somehow nonfunctional.

Comment: Could be a problem of improper mixing too.